# How function inside function work in python

Tags: python, function

I'm a new python learner and start with some exercises of string. And i'm wondering how '**replace**' function in '**matchcase**' actually work.

```
import re
a = 'UPPER PYTHON, lower python, Mixed Python'

def matchcase(word):
    def replace(m):
        text = m.group()
        if text.isupper():
            return word.upper()
        elif text.islower():
            return word.lower()
        elif text[0].isupper():
            return word.capitalize()
        else:
            return word
    return replace

print (matchcase('conran'))

print (re.sub('python',matchcase('conran'),a , flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

the output: UPPER CONRAN, lower conran, Mixed Conran

Comment: What exactly is unclear? `replace` works just like any other Python function.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you are unclear on?  `return replace` returns the function object.  This is called a *closure*.

Comment: `return replace` => `return replace(word)` or you're returning the function itself. In that case inner function isn't really useful.

Answer (score 1):

re.sub can take a function argument that is called on every match, instead of a text substitution.

Your outer function returns another function (higher order function) that has access to the passed string (this is called a closure). So this inner function gets called by re.sub with "python" and returns "conran" in the same case.

Comment: thanks you, now i understand how inner function work. :)

Comment: Hey Pepijn, could you help me to convert this function to a class. I tried but i haven't success at once.

Comment: What's wrong with a function? Don't use classes when you don't need to.